# Pytube throwing Error when getting Youtube Video Details

Tags: python, pytube

When I Run code For download YouTube Video or Getting Video details. I got following error

```
    C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\tube\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ankit/PycharmProjects/tube/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\tube\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\tube\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\tube\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 183, in prefetch
    self.js_url = extract.js_url(self.watch_html)
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\tube\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 143, in js_url
    base_js = get_ytplayer_config(html)["assets"]["js"]
KeyError: 'assets'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**This code is used**

```
    from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')

print(yt.title)

print(yt.streams)
```

Answer (score 3):

This error has now been fixed in the pytube repository. Just do a reinstall from the repo and it will work.

```
pip uninstall pytube
pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when the first two steps from the official documentation fail, you might have a broken library. I actually can't reproduce your error and am getting an import error from various other modules in the libary.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'quote' from 'pytube.compat'

and when I fixed this I got:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'urlencode' from 'pytube.compat'

at which point I gave up.

I seem to remember having the same or a similary issue when messing about with youtube stuff before. You can either follow the errors and try and fix the imports or just call it a day and try the 'youtube-dl' library:

pip install youtube_dl